# Would it be safe to manually create rows in a MySQL database rather than doing it via Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

We are migrating an old app that utilized regular SQL queries to read/write data from the database. For the new system, we're using Grails/Hibernate to store our data.

I'm not too familiar with how Hibernate stores stuff, so I'm reluctant to do anything too advanced. But our other developer (he doesn't know Hibernate either and is arguably less informed about modern development practices) really wants to use a script to map one set of tables to the other set.

So my question is: do you think it would be "safe" to create rows via some script and SQL, or would it be better to utilize Java code to create and write the domain objects instead? I know there is something to do with foreign keys, (which I don't know a whole lot about,) so it could be difficult to keep different rows pointing at each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the word "safe" is too broad.

> I know there is something to do with foreign keys, (which I don't know a whole lot about,)

**In your case, its not safe at all!**

If you have relations between tables, it will be worth coding the Grails domains accordingly, also the property as well.

There are other scenario where we need to insert data by running scripts manually, in that case we first become sure there is no violation of DB constraints.

As long as, there is **no violation**, its safe.

Whether the data manually inserted or not, Hibernate will map the data with corresponding domains.

Comment: "In your case, its not safe at all!" - That is a really misleading claim.  This is done all the time and it can be perfectly safe.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown yes, you are right. 
Btw, he mentioned a few times in same post, that he is "reluctant.."  and so on.
For, the beginners in hibernate, GORM and Grails domain, it might not be "safe" to run scripts without knowing what Grails can do it with. However,  I am sorry for "misleading claim".

Comment: Yeah, these are completely separate apps (different database structure), we wouldn't be able to simply export from one and import from the other. We'd have to make sure all the violations are accounted for. In the end, we just used code to do it to make sure everything is safe.

Answer (score 2):

You kind of need to know what you are doing but in general, populating your database with SQL is a fine thing to do and a common practice.  Often folks need to export data from one database and import it into another and that is routinely done with SQL scripts.